# MySQL - get average of value not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let's say I have a table with a specific ID (quiz id) and another data cell called `diff` which is the time in seconds it took to complete that quiz and put it in the DB.

I have this:

```
$doCommonQueryDiff = $mysqli->query("SELECT AVG(diff) FROM submissions WHERE quiz_id=$id")->fetch_array() or die($mysqli->error);
```

Later, when I do this to get the most common (or average?) of the data set, you will get the average of the all of the quizes it took in seconds.

I echo it using: `$doCommonQueryDiff['diff']` but I get: `Notice: Undefined index: diff` even though `diff` is in the database as a column.

Comment: `The AVG() function returns the average value of a numeric column.`. Is diff a numeric column?

Comment: try `$doCommonQueryDiff['AVG(diff)']` or change your query as `SELECT AVG(diff) AS diff ...`

Comment: @RoyMJ Yes, it is a numerical data. In seconds.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die($mysqli->error);` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT COUNT(\*) AS count - How to use this count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561154/select-count-as-count-how-to-use-this-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mysql when you use `AVG(diff)` column name will become `AVG(diff)` . then rename column name with diff

Try like this

```
$doCommonQueryDiff = $mysqli->query("SELECT AVG(diff) as diff FROM submissions WHERE quiz_id=$id")->fetch_array() or die($mysqli->error);
```