# SELECT COUNT(*) AS count - How to use this count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, count

Instead of doing:

```
$cars = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cars");
$count = $cars->num_rows();
if ($count) {
  // is rows
}
```

I want to not have to select all rows or a single column, I simply want the count.

In my head:

```
$cars = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM cars");
```

But then how do I use that count value? How can I get the result from `COUNT(*)` in PHP?

Answer (score 8):

It's not recommended to use reserved words for names in SQL. So I call the count result cnt instead. As your function is scalar, i.e. you expect only one value back, you can use:

```
$count = $mysqli->query("select count(*) as cnt from cars")->fetch_object()->cnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select queries always return a resultset.
To take the count, use `fetch_row()`

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cars`");
$cars= $result->fetch_row();
echo '#: ', $cars[0];// or use $c= $cars[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If result is an object then:

```
$cars = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM cars");
$carRows = $cars->result();
echo $carRows[0]->count;
```

If you return array then:

```
$cars = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM cars");
$carRows = $cars->result_array();
echo $carRows[0]['count'];
```

Comment: i can't find ->result(); or ->result_array(); anywhere in the php documentation

Answer (score 1):

You need to get first row of your result and see the 'count' column value:

```
$cars = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM cars");
$firstrow = $cars->fetch_assoc();

if ($firstrow['count'] > 0)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many options available to get the count from SQL.

If you are already on PHP 8.1, the simplest is this:

```
$count = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars")->fetch_column();
```

Here is a list of other possible methods:

- Using associative array:

```
$count = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM cars")->fetch_array()['count'];
```

- Using numerical array:

```
$count = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars")->fetch_array()[0];
```

- Using an object notation

```
$count = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM cars")->fetch_object()->count;
```

Important point. If you need to use variable input in your query then you should use prepared statement. To get the count then it would look like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars WHERE category=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $category);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];
```