# find the count of data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, count

I wish to find the count of certain items from database. i used this code

```
$sql=" SELECT count(*) from request WHERE status = '0'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($row);
                echo "</pre>";

            }
    }
```

i am getting this array in row

```
Array
(
    [count(1)] => 1
)
```

To fetch value from this array i used

```
$total = $row[0];
echo $total;
```

but did not get any result. how can i fetch value from this array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT COUNT(\*) AS count - How to use this count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561154/select-count-as-count-how-to-use-this-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
```

or change your query to:

```
$sql=" SELECT count(*) as `num` from request WHERE status = '0'";
```

and use:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
echo $row['num'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not need if condition in your code. You can do this

```
$sql=" SELECT * from request WHERE status = '0'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($row);
                echo "</pre>";

            }
```