# Mysqli - Equal and Different Expression

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having some problems with my query that is always returning false, but it should return true if not exists.
The problem is since the expression doesn't exists, it returns false.

```
function isRegistered($mysqli, $username, $sitename, $status){
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE username= ? AND sitename = ? AND status != ?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $sitename, $status);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows == 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm after that seeking if the function is true or false. If it's false, it throws an error, if it's true, it follows for the next step. The problem is that always coming false (even if that's not true).

Basically the user only can register once in a specific area. So the first time it should be allowed, and the second time it doesn't. Could someone check what's going wrong with my query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT COUNT(\*) AS count - How to use this count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561154/select-count-as-count-how-to-use-this-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of rows for an aggregation query is always 1.  If nothing matches the `WHERE` clause, then one row will be returned with the value of "1".

You can fix this either by changing the `SELECT COUNT(*)` to something non-aggregated, such as `SELECT 1` or `SELECT username`.  Or, you can read the value of `COUNT(*)` back from the query and use that.

I'll let you choose how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that a aggregation query is always 1. I selected some elements and then count them :) It works. Ill accept the answer as the site let me :)