# Why mysqli_data_seek isn't working after switching the code from mysql to mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently altered my code from using mysql to mysqli, and resolved all the errors displayed by WAMP local server. But the login mechanism is broken. Now it lets users to log in irrespective of the password being correct or incorrect. I am using the following function to do the work, which worked fine before switching things to mysqli. What is wrong here?

```
function login($registration_id, $password) {
    include 'core/database/connect.php';

    $registration_id = sanitize($registration_id);
    $password = sanitize($password);
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(`sr`) FROM `main_table` WHERE `registration_id` = '$registration_id' AND `password` = '$password'");
    return (mysqli_data_seek($query, 0) == 1) ? $registration_id : false;

    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: First of all, your code is vulnebra to sql injection. Escape them, or use prepared statements. Second, mysqli_close link never will run, before that you returns. (php automatically close connection when scripts end(.

Comment: Apparently, there is problem with `COUNT(\`sr\`)` in mysqli_query. I replaced it with simply `sr` and now it is working. But I don't have a clue about why this is so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELECT COUNT(\*) AS count - How to use this count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561154/select-count-as-count-how-to-use-this-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_data_seek()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) function just returns a Boolean value indicating if the call was successful or not. It does not return anything from the results of the underlying sql query.

Since your sql query is `select count(...)`, it will always return a single line in the resultset. So, unless sg goes wrong, the result of `mysqli_data_seek()` will be always true, which equals to 1. This means that everyone can log in.

You need to read the returned value by the `count()` function to determine if the login was successful using for example [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).