# How can I get the number of rows after executing a mysqli statement?

Tags: php, session, mysqli, row

I want to store in a session variable the number of rows that returns a statement, but I don´t know how. I´m trying doing it like this, but it doesn´t work.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT model, type, color FROM item WHERE model LIKE '%$type%'");


$stmt->execute();


$_SESSION['numRows'] = $stmt->num_rows;
echo $_SESSION['numRows'];

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$_SESSION['itemsInfo'] = $result->fetch_all();
```

Comment: why not just count your fetched data array? Also, what lib are you using? PDO? Mysqli? And you're missing a quote from a statement - not sure if that's like that in the code or just on here^^

Comment: I´m using Mysqli, and yes, the quote missing is only here. By the way, thank you, with count I think that works well

Comment: awesome :D I think there is a dupe for this, so may be closed, but you'll find a good answer there :)

Comment: See [How to get count of rows in MySQL table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58227521/1839439)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solve the problem, it works like this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT model, type, color FROM item WHERE model LIKE '%$type%'");


$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$_SESSION['itemsInfo'] = $result->fetch_all();
$_SESSION['numRows'] = count($_SESSION['itemsInfo']);
echo $_SESSION['numRows'];
```

Comment: Ok but you are getting the number of item of an array. The array contains all the results. IMHO is a workaround.

Comment: @sensorario which is how the data is returned anyway o.O not so much a workaround, it's more of a.... you probably should you the database object that has a property for that (IMO at least :p)

Comment: @sensorario so what? to count all the results is the question.

Comment: You are not using prepared statements correctly!