# Get number of rows inserted in last 2 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the count of visits from current IP address in last 2 minutes. This is the code I have tried, but the result is always zero.
Screen shot of my table is attached.
I have tried without prepared statement, it is also returning zero

```
<?php

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM visitors_activity where ip=? and visit_time > date_sub(now(), interval 2 minute) ');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$ip); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo $result->num_rows;
```

Screenshot of my table:
[image: Screenshot of my table]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get count of rows in MySQL table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227521/how-to-get-count-of-rows-in-mysql-table-using-php)

Comment: No @Dharman. ...

Comment: does your query return any data if you run it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Do you insert `visit_time` value using `NOW()` too ? Just to be sure they are on same hour

Comment: i got the solution and posted here as answer. I inserted time using $timestamp variable

Answer (score 0):

With the help of tips from you, i got the answer for my question

```
$timestamp=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   



$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM visitors_activity where ip=? and visit_time > date_sub(?, interval 2 minute) ');

$stmt->bind_param('ss',$ip,$timestamp); 


$stmt->execute();


$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo $result->num_rows;
```