# Getting zero back using count in SQL with prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am working on the following script. Why am I always getting `0` using the `COUNT(*)` in my query against MySQL using prepared statement?

```
$num_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl WHERE `tdisplay` = 1";
$stmt2 = $conn-> prepare($num_query);
$stmt2 -> execute();
$stmt2 -> store_result();
$rows = $stmt2->num_rows;
```

Comment: Assuming the query succeeded you should always get 1 row, the one 1 containing the `COUNT`.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am getting `0` and why `1` ? shouldn't It return all rows numbers? Same query in `PHPMyAdmin` is returning 414

Comment: You are checking the number of rows returned from the query. The query only returns one row, which has the count in it. Try replacing `$stmt2->store_result` with `$stmt2->bind_result($rows); $stmt2->fetch(); echo $rows;`

Comment: I can't reproduce. I always get 1.

Comment: Are you sure you have mysqli exceptions switched on? How are you checking the value of `$rows`?

Comment: @Nick, now I am getting `false` in return

Comment: It sounds like your query is failing somewhere. You need to add error checking...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Comment: Also: [How to get count of rows in MySQL table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58227521/1839439)