# How to display the result of SQL query in HTML?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table with 5 rows and I want to print the count of all the rows into a html `div`. I tried it like this:

```
$sqlassets = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assets";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sqlassets);
$log=var_dump($result);
```

and then I tried to use this variable in HTML:

```
<div class="col mr-2">
<div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Count of cars</div>
<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><?php print($log) ?></div>
</div>
```

but the result is:

> object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Yes, it is a result object. Fetch it! https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @user3783243, I am beginner in this, please can you help me with the code?

Comment: You can use either a `while` or `foreach` loop along with an alias for `COUNT()`.

Comment: Please click the link I sent. It has examples in it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No need for iterating, it is only 1 row returned.

Comment: @user3783243 OP => *"I have a sql table with 5 rows"*.

Comment: Well question is unclear I guess, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assets` will only bring back 1 row. If OP knows how many rows there are counting isn't needed.

Comment: @amir.mahajna Please clarify what you are trying to get. A count of all rows in table, a count of rows that meet some criteria, a sum of some column?

Comment: See [How to get count of rows in MySQL table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58227907/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` is an object of class `mysqli_result`. You need to fetch the first column from the first row. You can do it via `fetch_row()[0]`

```
$sqlassets = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assets";
$result = $conn->query($sqlassets);
$numOfRows = $result->fetch_row()[0];
var_dump($numOfRows);
```

You can then use the contents of that variable in the HTML:

```
<div class="col mr-2">
    <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Count of cars</div>
    <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><?php print($numOfRows) ?></div>
</div>
```