# SQL not providing proper result. (Using PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So here I have a table of Products which contains `ID`, `Name`, `Type` & `Price`

Now I'm running a function to give me the minimal price of specific product types.

The datatype of `Price` is `Price int(5,2)`

```
function MinPrice($connection) {

    echo "Minimum price: <br>";


    $sql = "SELECT Type, min(Price)
            FROM Products
            GROUP BY Type;";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      //Printing the result
      echo $row['Type'].'  ||  '.$row['Price'].'<br>';
    }
  }
```

The code works but not properly. I get the names of the product types but for the price, it gives me an error.

`Undefined index: Price`

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get count of rows in MySQL table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227521/how-to-get-count-of-rows-in-mysql-table-using-php)

Comment: Your SQL is returning the correct results, you are just not displaying them. See the link, it should help you understand few things. I would also recommend using `foreach` instead of `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Type, min(Price) as Price
            FROM Products
            GROUP BY Type;";
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "try this" please? I know what you did but future readers may not.

Comment: Why did you suggest this? Why do you think that this is a good solution?